# Allowing User to Create a Key and Value in Swift userdefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I currently have my app adding a value to two different keys in userDefaults
the values being added are a "Song Name" and the "BPM" (beats per minute) 
the two keys are sName and sBPM.

What I want to do is let the user create the Key with the song name and the value being the BPM. which would allow them to select a song from a UiPickerView and the app could display the BPM.

Basically. How do i let the user create a key from a text input rather than giving a value to a pre created key.

Hopefully this makes sense. I am very new to Swift and programming in general

Comment: The key is just a string, and the text input is just a string, so there's no difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you have a UITextField on your UI for entering both Song Name and BMP Value, with a reference to it in your code as songTextField and bmpTextField respectively, when return Key is Tapped or whenever you want to perform the operation, you can use the below code

```
if let songName = songTextField.text, let bmpValue = bmpTextField.text {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(bmpValue, forKey: songName)
}
```

Comment: Hi Deepika, yes the user will enter both values, for example the UI has 2 text inputs one for song name and one for bpm, so they would enter “Hotel California” in the name field and “74” in the BPM field. The name would then get added to a UI pickerview and when it was clicked in the pickerview it would display “74” in a label.

Comment: And the user would be able to add multiple songs into the app

Comment: I have updated the answer. How are you maintaining the dataSource to the UIPickerView. you can append the songName to the dataSource just below where you are setting values in your UserDefaults

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you can set the kay as SongName & the BPM value as its value. Like below code

```
let songs = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]
let BPMValue = 1.5

UserDefaults.standard.set(BPMValue, forKey: songs[index])
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

With the Song and value associated with each other and key will be a unique

Comment: Thank Karamjeet, so each time the user adds a song and its bpm it will create a new key being the song name and the value being the bpm?

Answer (score 0):

create a Struct for details you want for Song

```
struct songDetails {
   var songName : String
   var songBPM : String
}
```

Now you can create a array using this struct type,

```
var songDetailsArray : [songDetails] = []
```

And you can add new song in array by taking inputs from the UITextFields

```
songDetailsArray.append(songDetails(songName: songNameTextField.text!, songBPM: bpmTextField.text!))
```

And easily add it in UIPIckerView by using the same array

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return songDetailsArray[row].songName
}
```

You can select a song from UIPickerView and Access its name by

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
   let songName = songDetailsArray[row].songName
   let correspondingBpm = songDetailsArray[row].songBPM
   print(correspondingBpm)        //this is the corresponding bmp to the seleced song name 
   UserDefaults.standard.set(songName, forKey: "sName")
   UserDefaults.standard.set(correspondingBpm, forKey: "sBPM")
}
```

Here you are creating only two UserDefaults value for your song and correspondingBPM.

And You can access this UserDefaults value anywhere in the project by

```
let songName = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "sName")
let songBPM = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "sBPM")
```

This might help you, you can find the BPM corresponding to Song Name now

Comment: Thanks Yashvir, I am now getting a SIGABRT error, it looks like it is because of this:

 ".ViewController numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb6db70d690"

I copied that from the output log, I think it is to do with not calling UIPickerView after UIViewController

Comment: include [UIPickerViewDataSource] and [UIPickerViewDelegate] in your UIViewController class, and you also have to assign their Delegates to Self

Comment: So I am now able to add to userdefaults and I have opened the plist file where UD are stored and I can see it is being saved and displayed in the plist the way I want. However. nothing is displaying in my pickerview. 

What should I be checking to find the issue here?

Comment: your must be songDetailsArray must be empty